# How to calculate difference and aggregate energy as a counter - TimescaleDB

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

I've got time series data in TimescaleDB from smart meters, the Energy value is stored as a counter.

I have 2 questions:

1) How do I calculate the difference between each row of energy values so I can just see the increase minute by minute for each row?

2) I've got this in 1 minute intervals and I'd like to aggregate as 30m, 60m etc. What's the best way of achieving this?

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of challenges here. First, you have to make sure that the intervals of your counter indexes are constant (think communication outages,...) . If not, you'll have to deal with the resulting energy peaks. 
Second, your index will probably look like a discrete jigsaw signal, restarting at zero once in a while.

Here's how we did it.
For 2), we use as many continuous aggregates on the indexes as we require resolutions (15min, 60min,...). Use locf where required. 
For 1) we do the delta computation on the fly. Meaning that we query the db for the indexes and then loop through the array to compute the delta. This way we can easily handle the jigsaw and peaks.

Answer (score 0):

I've just got an answer to my question, which is very similar to your Part 1, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68937639/calculating-the-change-of-a-value-versus-the-last-reading-in-timescaledb)

In short, the answer I got was to use a before_insert trigger and calculate the difference values on insertion, storing them in a new column. This avoids needing to re-calculate deltas on every query.

I extended the function suggested in the Answer by also calculating the delta_time with

```
NEW.delta_time = EXTRACT (EPOCH FROM NEW.time - previous_time);
```

This returns the number of seconds which have passed, allowing you to calculate meter power reliably.

For Part 2, consider a [Continuous Aggregate with time buckets](https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/how-to-guides/query-data/advanced-analytic-queries/#gap-filling) as suggested above